# How to implement social network cards (feed) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS development and I need to make something like News Feed on Facebook app. How can I make those "cards"? I've found some [Android lib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) for cards, but I can't find it anywhere for iOS. Could you give me some concept at least how it should be done? Should I make some View "Feed" in .xib file and load it after to scroll view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a UITableView, and make each of the "cards" a custom UITableViewCell class. Create a subclass of UIViewController to act as the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate, and then back that with some kind of data manager that handles asynchronous network communication and object marshaling before pushing it up to the front end.